# Como obtengo el id de un documento en especial en firestore para luego pasarlo a un componente y poder usar su informacion?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, firestore

Quiero obtener el id de un documento usando firestore para poder accerder a la info.
Quiero obtener un id en especial, cuando me logeo quiero acceder al id de un documento.
[image: Quiero obtener ese id]

Aqui me estoy logeando, y puedo acceder al UID que me brinda firebase, pero necesito acceder al ID del documento que tengo en firestore

```
const handleSingIn = async () => {
    try {
      console.log(auth, email, password);
      const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      let id = user.uid;
      console.log("account entro");
      return navigation.navigate("HomeScreen", {uid: id});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error al entrar");
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

y en firebaseconfig tengo la base de datos

```
export const database = getFirestore();
```

yo necesito poder obtener ese id cuando me logeo y mandarlo a otro componente para poder utilizarlo.
Estoy usando react-native, javascript y typescript.

```
const HomeScreen = ({ route ,navigation }: RootStackScreenProps<"HomeScreen">) => {
  

  const { uid } = route.params

  const [data, setData] = useState<any>({
  });
  console.log('uuid', uid)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const queryDoc = doc(database, 'people',uid);
        console.log('query', queryDoc);
        const info = await getDoc(queryDoc);
        const name = info.data();
        console.log('name', name)
        setData(name);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    getData();
  }, []);
```

en este componente lo quiero usar

Comment: Que tipo hay aqui `console.log('uuid', uid)`, es `undefined`?